# Java method not working in nested classes

Tags: java, inner-classes, outer-classes

I have 1 outer class with 1 inner class like this:

```
public class Outer extends PircBot { 
...
public class Inner extends SessionAdapter { 
...    
}
}
```

Inside that `Inner` class I am trying to invoke a method called `sendMessage(..)` which is inside `PircBot` (and not in `Outer` class. But of course I know all fields in `Outer` and `Pircbot` classes are inherited in the `Inner` class):

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(SessionEvent event) { //This method is inside SessionAdapter class which I am extending in my Inner class
Outer.this.sendMessage(event.getMessage()); //This method is inside Pircbot class which I am extending in my Outer class
}
```

I know for a fact that `sendMessage(..)` method is called. But for some reason I don't see that message on Twitch chat (This program sends chat messages to Twitch Chat. Those chat messages are received from the Yahoo Chat Messenger from my Phone when I type them). Can anyone see what is wrong with my code?

Comment: If you know for a fact that sendMessage is called, then your problem probably lies in the sendMessage method (which you didn't post). Which makes it difficult to help.

Comment: Okay I read this and you can close this as far as I'm concerned, but I should mention I'm not the one who favorited this question, so there might be somebody else trying to find an answer to this. Thanks for the consideration though.

Comment: If you discover the answer, please add the answer to an answer block. Please do not mangle the title with [solved], and please do not append the answer to the question - we prefer questions and answers to be clearly delineated here, not least to improve the data supplied in the SE API. Would you edit? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did. I changed the position of the instantiation of inner class (from inside the default outer constructor to instance variable). Like this:

**From**

```
public class Outer extends PircBot { 
private int x;
public Outer(){
x = 5;
Inner n = new Inner(); //Instantiation inside Outer class's default constructor
}
public class Inner extends SessionAdapter { 
...    
}
}
```

**To**

```
public class Outer extends PircBot { 
private int x;
Inner n = new Inner(); //Now instantiation is outside constructor
public Outer(){
x = 5;
//no more instantiation inside constructor 
}
public class Inner extends SessionAdapter { 
...    
}
}
```

Also, it may have been a twitch thing. Sometimes the capitalization of channel names doesn't work. It requires capitalization of letters in certain way. So I changed the capitalization of letters in a String (weird but whatever).